# How to learn to create a landing page like this by pure HTML & CSS

Tags: website-design

I've found [a nice landing page](https://2x.ant.design/) which is built under *ant design* - a ReactJS UI framework.
I suspect someone doesn't need to go that far to learn ReactJS in order to built something similar. So I ask here how to do it in HTML&CSS.

The part that I want to replicate is the animation of moving objects and text from left and right into the center. This happens when a user scrolls down while visiting the page.

If my question is too broad, I hope that at least I still can get alternative feedback such as a pointer to other similar pages built with HTML&CSS. I don't mind if I have to study the code by myself.

Comment: Hi Prska, welcome to GDSE. We are a Q&A site for everything design related. Since your question is about learning HTML and CSS, I have closed it as off-topic. There are enough libraries and tutorials out there that can teach you how to animate on scroll using CSS and javascript.

Comment: @PieBie Given the general nature of many how-to questions related to graphic design programs, I think this question is on topic for GD.SE. I think it could use an edit to be more precise though.

Comment: The core approach is firing an animation using either the [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) or simply the scroll position of the page. A good article on how to do scroll animations with [GSAP](https://greensock.com/), the most common web animation library, can be found [here](https://medium.com/elegant-seagulls/parallax-and-scroll-triggered-animations-with-the-intersection-observer-api-and-gsap3-53b58c80b2fa). Disclaimer: I currently work for GreenSock. But the approach I mention is not tied to GSAP in any way.